# Infinite recursive template instantiation expected?

Tags: templates, c++11, c++14, sfinae

I am trying to understand why a piece of template metaprogramming is **not** generating an infinite recursion. I tried to reduce the test case as much as possible, but there's still a bit of setup involved, so bear with me :)

The setup is the following. I have a generic function `foo(T)` which delegates the implementation to a generic functor called `foo_impl` via its call operator, like this:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct foo_impl {};

template <typename T>
inline auto foo(T x) -> decltype(foo_impl<T>{}(x))
{
    return foo_impl<T>{}(x);
}
```

`foo()` uses decltype trailing return type for SFINAE purposes. The default implementation of `foo_impl` does not define any call operator. Next, I have a type-trait that detects whether `foo()` can be called with an argument of type `T`:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_foo
{
    struct yes {};
    struct no {};
    template <typename T1>
    static auto test(T1 x) -> decltype(foo(x),void(),yes{});
    static no test(...);
    static const bool value = std::is_same<yes,decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))>::value;
};
```

This is just the classic implementation of a type trait via expression SFINAE:
`has_foo<T>::value` will be true if a valid `foo_impl` specialisation exists for `T`, false otherwise. Finally, I have two specialisations of the the implementation functor for integral types and for floating-point types:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_impl<T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{
    void operator()(T) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct foo_impl<T,typename std::enable_if<has_foo<unsigned>::value && std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
{
    void operator()(T) {}
};
```

In the last `foo_impl` specialisation, the one for floating-point types, I have added the extra condition that `foo()` must be available for the type `unsigned` (`has_foo<unsigned>::value`).

What I don't understand is why the compilers (GCC & clang both) accept the following code:

```
int main()
{
    foo(1.23);
}
```

In my understanding, when `foo(1.23)` is called the following should happen:

1. the specialisation of `foo_impl` for integral types is discarded because `1.23` is not integral, so only the second specialisation of `foo_impl` is considered;
2. the enabling condition for the second specialisation of `foo_impl` contains `has_foo<unsigned>::value`, that is, the compiler needs to check if `foo()` can be called on type `unsigned`;
3. in order to check if `foo()` can be called on type `unsigned`, the compiler needs again to select a specialisation of `foo_impl` among the two available;
4. at this point, in the enabling condition for the second specialisation of `foo_impl` the compiler encounters again the condition `has_foo<unsigned>::value`.
5. GOTO 3.

However, it seems like the code is happily accepted both by GCC 5.4 and Clang 3.8. See here: http://ideone.com/XClvYT

I would like to understand what is going on here. Am I misunderstanding something and the recursion is blocked by some other effect? Or maybe am I triggering some sort of undefined/implementation defined behaviour?

Comment: try changing the unsigned in your example to float and see what happens. Upon that change substitution failure occurs. unsigned will be evaluated by is_integral to be true. So, I think it checks first the second foo_impl then the first one is vacuously true.

Comment: [Infinite recursion in template instantiation is undefined behavior.](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#14)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`has_foo<unsigned>::value` is a non-dependent expression, so it immediately triggers instantiation of `has_foo<unsigned>` (even if the corresponding specialization is never used).

The relevant rules are [temp.point]/1:

> For a function template specialization, a member function template specialization, or a specialization for a member function or static data member of a class template, if the specialization is implicitly instantiated because it is referenced from within another template specialization and the context from which it is referenced depends on a template parameter, the point of instantiation of the specialization is the point of instantiation of the enclosing specialization. Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization immediately follows the namespace scope declaration or definition that refers to the specialization.

(note that we're in the non-dependent case here), and [temp.res]/8:

> The program is
>   ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>    - [...]
>    -  a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or
>    -  the interpretation of such a construct in the hypothetical instantiation is different from the interpretation of the corresponding construct in any actual instantiation of the template.

These rules are intended to give the implementation freedom to instantiate `has_foo<unsigned>` at the point where it appears in the above example, and to give it the same semantics as if it had been instantiated there. (Note that the rules here are actually subtly wrong: the point of instantiation for an entity referenced by the declaration of another entity *actually* must immediately precede that entity rather than immediately following it. This has been reported as a core issue, but it's not on the issues list yet as the list hasn't been updated for a while.)

As a consequence, the point of instantiation of `has_foo` within the floating-point partial specialization occurs before the point of declaration of that specialization, which is after the `>` of the partial specialization per [basic.scope.pdecl]/3:

> The point of declaration for a class or class template first declared by a class-specifier is immediately after the identifier or simple-template-id (if any) in its class-head (Clause 9).

Therefore, when the call to `foo` from `has_foo<unsigned>` looks up the partial specializatios of `foo_impl`, it does not find the floating-point specialization at all.

**A couple of other notes about your example:**

1) Use of cast-to-`void` in comma operator:

```
static auto test(T1 x) -> decltype(foo(x),void(),yes{});
```

This is a bad pattern. `operator,` lookup is *still* performed for a comma operator where one of its operands is of class or enumeration type (even though it can never succeed). This can result in ADL being performed [implementations are permitted but not required to skip this], which triggers the instantiation of all associated classes of the return type of foo (in particular, if `foo` returns `unique_ptr<X<T>>`, this can trigger the instantiation of `X<T>` and may render the program ill-formed if that instantiation doesn't work from this translation unit). You should prefer to cast all operands of a comma operator of user-defined type to `void`:

```
static auto test(T1 x) -> decltype(void(foo(x)),yes{});
```

2) SFINAE idiom:

```
template <typename T1>
static auto test(T1 x) -> decltype(void(foo(x)),yes{});
static no test(...);
static const bool value = std::is_same<yes,decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))>::value;
```

This is not a correct SFINAE pattern in the general case. There are a few problems here:

- if `T` is a type that cannot be passed as an argument, such as `void`, you trigger a hard error instead of `value` evaluating to `false` as intended
- if `T` is a type to which a reference cannot be formed, you again trigger a hard error
- you check whether `foo` can be applied to an lvalue of type `remove_reference<T>` *even if* `T` is an rvalue reference

A better solution is to put the entire check into the `yes` version of `test` instead of splitting the `declval` portion into `value`:

```
template <typename T1>
static auto test(int) -> decltype(void(foo(std::declval<T1>())),yes{});
template <typename>
static no test(...);
static const bool value = std::is_same<yes,decltype(test<T>(0))>::value;
```

This approach also more naturally extends to a ranked set of options:

```
// elsewhere
template<int N> struct rank : rank<N-1> {};
template<> struct rank<0> {};


template <typename T1>
static no test(rank<2>, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T1, double>::value>* = nullptr);
template <typename T1>
static yes test(rank<1>, decltype(foo(std::declval<T1>()))* = nullptr);
template <typename T1>
static no test(rank<0>);
static const bool value = std::is_same<yes,decltype(test<T>(rank<2>()))>::value;
```

Finally, your type trait will evaluate faster and use less memory at compile time if you move the above declarations of `test` outside the definition of `has_foo` (perhaps into some helper class or namespace); that way, they do not need to be redundantly instantiated once for each use of `has_foo`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my call! :)

Comment: Ah! I didn't even bother trying to find rules for whether the specialization is visible (and instead chased the hypothesis of incompleteness), because I fully missed the implications of when exactly non-dependent template classes are instantiated. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: ...also I now have a weird feeling that all this means that this is basically covered by the limerick, which would be a yet another thing I've completely ignored while reading the standardese yesterday. Shame on me.

Comment: @Richard Smith many many thanks, both for the answer and the SFINAE explanations! I have a question: what are examples of types to which a reference cannot be formed (apart from ``void``)? Also, in the snippet of code right after "A better solution.." is that a typo of using ``std::declval<T>()`` rather than ``std::declval<T1>()`` or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Ven and Griwes: thanks a lot for going to such long way in investigating this! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @bluescarni It's a typo, now fixed, thanks! In addition to *cv* `void`, you also can't form a reference to an "abominable function type" (one with *cv-* or *ref-qualifier*s)

Answer (score 11):

It's not actually UB. But it really shows you how TMP is complex...

The reason this doesn't infinitely recurse is because of completeness.

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_impl<T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{
    void operator()(T) {}
};

// has_foo here

template <typename T>
struct foo_impl<T,typename std::enable_if<has_foo<unsigned>::value && std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
{
    void operator()(T) {}
};
```

When you call `foo(3.14);`, you instantiate `has_foo<float>`. That in turn SFINAEs on `foo_impl`.

The first one is enabled if `is_integral`. Obviously, this fails.

The second `foo_impl<float>` is now considered. Trying to instantiate it, the compiles sees `has_foo<unsigned>::value`.

Back to instantiating `foo_impl`: `foo_impl<unsigned>`!

The first `foo_impl<unsigned>` is a match.

The second one is considered. The `enable_if` contains `has_foo<unsigned>` - the one the compiler is already trying to instantiate.

Since it's currently being instantiated, it's **incomplete**, and this specialization is not considered.

Recursion stops, `has_foo<unsigned>::value` is true, and your code snippet works!

---

So, you want to know how it comes down to it in the standard? Okay.

> [14.7.1/1] If a class template has been declared, but not defined, at the point of instantiation ([temp.point]), the instantiation yields an incomplete class type.

(incomplete)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Do you have any reference to the relevant standard section for me to study? Or a cppreference link or something like that :)

Comment: Uhhh. I'm going to forget about the basic fact that you're trying to kill me, and try to extract that legalese for you...

Comment: Not even a small pointer? :) I don't fully understand 2 things: 1) when you say it's "incomplete", do you mean as in "incomplete type"? 2) the incompleteness causes the specialisation to SFINAE out or is there some other mechanism at work?

Comment: 1) yes. That's the part I found already. I'm gonna to submit the edit I'm preparing. I'm still trying to find justification for 2), but it should go along the lines of "incomplete type = subst. fialure"

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I did not know that incomplete types would sfinae out - I just tried on clang/gcc on a trivial example and it seems to be working like that indeed.

Comment: There's no type deduction here, I think.

Comment: There's this: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#6, but I can't find any normative text that explains how this applies to templates, and I'm not convinced it implicitly does in some magic way. Basically what we need is a piece of normative text that says that currently instantiated templated classes (i.e. the classes that result from instantiation of a class template) are incomplete types, and I've failed to find one.

Comment: @Griwes but even in presence of such a piece of normative text, we would still be in a situation where there's no deduction taking place, wouldn't we? If you use a non-deduced incomplete type as part of the enabling condition, it should be a hard error rather than SFINAE out, shouldn't it?

Comment: @bluescarni I'm pretty sure that doing a member access into an incomplete type counts as expression SFINAE, so no problem there. (By the way that's how the `void_t` technique works; go read about it, it makes writing the `has_foo` trait incredibly easier.) I'm not sure why you seem so fixed on deduction - there's no deduction taking place really, just substitutions.

Comment: @Griwes https://ideone.com/KhvYx8 this is what I mean, if the argument to ``is_unsigned`` it the deduced template type ``T`` then it sfinaes out, but if you use ``is_unsigned<unsigned>`` it's a hard error.

Comment: @bluescarni Ah. The term you're looking isn't "deduced", but "dependent name". SFINAE only works when dependent names are involved, yes.

Comment: @bluescarni should I add it to the answer?

Comment: @Ven sure! But I am not sure I understand well what the current status of the discussion is. The 2 stumbling blocks that I see are: 1) it's unclear whether a type being currently instantiated is incomplete 2) I don't understand how SFINAE can kick in for ``has_foo<unsigned>::value``  as there's nothing depending on the template parameter in that expression.

Comment: I called in to @Griwes and jaggedSpire for some help, and we were unable to find something that was more meaningful than what I and griwes posted.

Comment: @bluescarni I believe (...since now that you've asked this, I'm no longer sure of it) SFINAE kicks in for the entire expression, because there's a dependent name in the expression (`T`, as an argument to `is_floating_poin`). [Here](https://github.com/griwes/reaveros-iteration1/blob/develop/kernel/utils/types.h#L50)'s an example of that happening; it's slightly different, but I believe the same rules are at work in both cases.

Comment: @Griwes In the example you posted the non-deduced parts (``std::is_same<T, uint64_t>::value && std::is_same<::virtual_address_tag, Tag>::value``) can never generate invalid expressions, as the ``value`` member of ``std::is_same`` is always present. If you take a look at this: https://ideone.com/KhvYx8 you can see that an incomplete type not depending on the template parameter results in a hard error (or at least that's my interpretation of the compiler error message :).

Comment: @Griwes sorry I had edited the ideone link by mistake, it should be correct now.

Comment: Okay, there must be some weird core language rule about this. I'm going to go into observer mode, since I have reached the limits of my core wording knowledge, and of my core language specification grepping :D